# Similar but not same string sequence

Tags: java, regex

How to match the following sequence:

```
You wound DUMMY TARGET for 100 points of damage
```

but not:

```
You wound DUMMY TARGET with SKILL for 100 points of damage
```

with the regular expression:

```
^You wound ([\\w\\s]+)(?!with) for (\\d+) points of damage
```

The regular expression above is matching both strings while i expect to match only the first one. Is there any way to make this work?

Sample Java code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Dummy {

 static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^You wound ([\\w\\s]+)(?!with) for (\\d+) points of damage");
 static Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("");
 static String FIRST_SEQUENCE =  "You wound DUMMY TARGET for 100 points of damage";
 static String SECOND_SEQUENCE =  "You wound DUMMY TARGET with SKILL for 100 points of damage";

 public static void main(String...args) {  
  if (matcher.reset(FIRST_SEQUENCE).matches())
   System.out.println("First match. Ok!");

  if (matcher.reset(SECOND_SEQUENCE).matches())
   System.out.println("Second match. Wrong!");
 }
}
```

Comment: "with SKILL" is always fixed?

Comment: The word "with" is always fixed. Skill can be one or more words spaced.

These are the real sequence examples:

"You wound the Ongbúrz Berserker for 68 points of Ancient Dwarf-make damage."

"You wound the Ongbúrz Berserker with Anthem of the Valar for 215 points of Ancient Dwarf-make damage."

Answer (score 3):

Try with non-greedy operator +? , `([\\w\\s]+?)`

```
^You wound ([\\w\\s]+?)(?!with) for (\\d+) points of damage
```

Comment: I think you need 2 regex and match for second one first like this, `"You wound ([\\w\\s]+?) with \\w+ for (\\d+) points of damage"`, and if its match, skip it, else, match with `^You wound ([\\w\\s]+?) for (\\d+) points of damage`

Comment: The solution will work fine using conditionals. But i'm looking for a way to match this with a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

also, if the string to be matched is always upper case, you can try :

```
^You wound ([A-Z\s]+) for (\d+) points of damage
```

Comment: The sequence can be anything from "Some dude" to "Dude" or "Some-Dude".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

"^You wound [A-Za-z0-9 ][^with]+ for [0-9]+ points of damage"

worked for me